# Accordion panel with visible option using jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am very new to jQuery.
I want create a an accordion panel using jQuery with a visibility option.

Is it possible to set visible false for an accordion control in jQuery?

Comment: Hello did you check the answers below?

Comment: Ya. But it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  is what you want I understand http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/03/accordion-madness.

Enjoy coding.

Comment: Hi, Now its working fine. I want to hide the header on some condition basis. is it possible?

Comment: @Nathiya Up Vote for answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

See [**Accordion**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use an [accordion plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion) - or if it's simple enough, roll your own

```
$('#my-list li').css({ display: none }).click(function() { $(this).slideToggle(500); });
```

Check out docs for [selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors), [css](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS), [event handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) and [effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects) to learn how this works. It's very basic, but I often only ever need the basics, and it's sure better than incorporating an ~8kb (or more) plugin.